# My software updater is stuck on "configuring grub-efi-amd64" how can I fix it?

Tags: dell, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series that cam pre-loaded with Ubuntu, I am trying to update it, but for the second time the software updater gets greyed out. The first time I rebooted it but I ended up having to restore ubuntu.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

The pre-installed ubuntu may be corrupt. You can fix it by doing this:

You should burn Ubuntu to a disc or flash drive if you have another computer by following this tutorial: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

If you can not, you can buy one from the ubuntu store: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Then install it onto your system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP has already reinstalled.